# testing - Android devices with lowest specs

Tags: android, device, android-2.2-froyo

I want to test on Android devices with the lowest specs but I don't know which device that is

A device with less than 160dpi screen, less than 256mb RAM, less than 3.5 inch screen.

and using Android 2.2+

I have seen the lists on wikipedia but they don't mention how much RAM. and there is no good way to specifically filter 2.2+

At first glance it seems as if the low-end devices have been weeded out by 2.2 but this is probably a fallacy given the number of android devices.

This is further compounded by the fact that "knockoff" devices have 512mb ram these days, but the obscure budget carriers may still have some strange devices out there I've never heard of

please list low powered devices running 2.2+ or greater. I've used the emulator but this doesn't give me real world results too often.

Comment: We've got a Huawei U8150 Ideos: 240 x 320 pixels, 2.8" (~143 ppi), Qualcomm MSM7225 @ 528 MHz (+ Adreno 200), 256 MB RAM, Android 2.2. For some compatibility testing we're also using a Samsung Galaxy Spica with 2.1-update1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i usually use the following device for low end device compatibility tests:

- sony ericsson xperia x10 mini ( 240x320; very small screen )
- samsung galaxy 3 ( small screen 240x400 )

the x10 mini's latest android update is 2.1; the galaxy 3 has a 2.2 update, so maybe the latter would be a good low end testing device for you.